# Using gsub or sub to replace one character

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I want to replace only the third character of a string by its upper case counterpart. Using `gsub` or `sub` is causing the following error:

```
"Hiiiii".sub!(string[2,1],string[2,1].upcase!) # => hIiiii

"Hello".gsub!(string[2,1],string[2,1].upcase!) # => heLLo
```

While `gsub` unexpectedly replaced all similar characters, `sub` replaced the first occurrence, irrespective of the position I mention.

Can anyone suggest how I can make `sub` work only after the third character?

Comment: If you want to modify just part of a string, as specified by character offsets, it's often easier to break up the string, make the change and then reconstruct; e.g., `s = "Howyadoin?"; s= s[0,3] + s[3,2].upcase + s[5..-1] => "HowYAdoin?"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expression with a **Positive Lookbehind** to do this. Lookarounds do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

```
"Hiiiii".sub(/(?<=..)./, &:upcase)
 # => "HiIiii"
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=       # look behind to see if there is:
  .        #  any character except \n
  .        #  any character except \n
)          # end of look-behind
.          # any character except \n
```

Answer (score 6):

Use simple method as below using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) to access the specific character and [`String#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) to substitute any specific character.

```
str = "Hiiiii"
str[2] = str[2].upcase
str # => "HiIiii"
```

Comment: Thank u.. How can I do this if I'm not supposed to use these internal methods??

Comment: means , when not supposed to use internal methods (of String class). Was an assignment :) and its Karnataka..

Comment: @akshatha Ohh!! Same city... we are.. Great!

Answer (score 6):

When you want to pass a certain pattern whose length can be determined prior to the match by a regex, you can use positive lookbehind to pass that pattern.

It is better to use `sub!` as it applies only once (rather than using `gsub!` with anchoring `\A` as in hwnd's answer before edit).

```
"Hiiiii".sub!(/(?<=.{2})./, &:upcase)
# => "HiIiii"

"Hello".sub!(/(?<=.{2})./, &:upcase)
# => "HeLlo"
```